# Why would the author use the word "awhile"? Is it unnecessary?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, syntactic-analysis, sentence

Quote: "Sitting awhile in the sun, she might make some sense of the problem"

Why use "awhile" while one can just use "while"?

Why one can awhile just use "While", would use "awhile?" [Does this even make sense]

Answer (score 3):

Awhile is an adverb, it states the length of time in this case.

A while is a noun, it means a short time.

After a preposition, you´ll have a "NOUN".  (Now let´s LINK everything together).

I can now say:
Sitting awhile in the sun, she came to her senses. (Adverb: How long? some time, awhile)

With a preposition:

Sitting for a while in the sun, she came to her senses. (Preposition "For" follow by a noun "a while")  (It´s a noun because we have an article "a" before it.)

Whichever one you choose, it´s just a matter of writing style.

Comment: You might also address “Sitting while in the sun” for a complete answer to OP’s question.

Answer (score 1):

While  is  a conjunction  as  well  as  a  noun and  even  a  verb too.

A while  means  for  some  time.

> Sitting awhile in the  sun, she  might  make  some  sense  of  a  problem.

A  *while*   is  a  noun  phrase  meaning  a  period  of  time  and   *awhile*   is   an  adverb  meaning   for  a time.

> While  he  was  playing, I was  reading.

Here  *while*  is  a conjunction   meaning  when.

> He  whiled  away  his  time  uselessly.

Here  *while*  is  a  verb meaning  spend.

Here     are  two links  which  helps you  know  the  differences.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/while

https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/while-versus-awhile

Answer (score 0):

awhile = for a short time; it is different from 'while' in usage.
This, if replaced with its meaning, will be, "Sitting for a short time in the sun...."